# How to use GIT with Pega?

Tags: git, pega

I am new to `Pega` and I know nothing about pega.

My company is trying to use `GIT` instead of **'build in'** source control.

I referred Google I hardly find few links and it was not that helpful

Kindly let me know whether `GIT` can be integrated to `PEGA` instead of built-in source control

Comment: Didn't you find this? It was the 4th result in google for me: https://community1.pega.com/community/pega-product-support/question/how-use-git-source-control-pega It's couple years old though.

Comment: Yes I had gone through that already and I've been searching for a precise answer about the possibility.  Few asked about 'GIT support on Pega' however they were replied that 'Pega' itself is capable of handling everything from SCM perspective

Answer (score 1):

Pega stores all the code (a.k.a rules in Pega world) as compiled classes in its Rules DB schema. So technically there is not source code that can be source controlled through any external SCM like Git. Pega provides in house versioning mechanism and guess that is the only option now.